# What are the consequences of leaving my chicken in a mine?

Tags: harvest-moon-back-to-nature

Suppose I bring a chicken into a mine, and leave it there. What's going to happen to the chicken? Will it be automatically fed (much like how I don't need to feed the chickens who are left outside the chicken coop)? Is there an increased risk that the chicken could die?